# User-Defined type not defined. Macro runs stepping through but not when ran as a button

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that takes data from one sheet then adds a graph to another sheet. The macro works when I step through it but when I use a form button to call the macro, I get

> **`User-defined type not defined.`**

Most these errors, from my research, are related to references for outside programs which my code has none of. Also, my code used to work without issue but upon coming back to it months later, I now also get an

> **`"unexpected error / Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"`**

alert when this new sheet gets added. It's not in the typical format, either. It allows for a link to be clicked: "Copy Details" (does nothing), Send a Frown (alerts MS), or close. Display alerts = false didn't fix this, I'm guessing because it's more a bug than an issue with the macro?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Graph()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim Chart As Chart
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim srs1 As Series
Dim srs3 As Series
Dim srs4 As Series
Dim srs5 As Series
Dim srs6 As Series
Dim srs7 As Series
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'data to be turned into graph
Range("A36:H" & LastRow).Select

With Selection
    Set Chart = Charts.Add
End With

With Chart
    .HasTitle = True

'determine which chart title to add
    If Worksheets("Margin View").Range("R1").Value = 2 Then
        .ChartTitle.Text = Range("=Functions!T17").Value
        .PlotBy = xlColumns
    Else
        .ChartTitle.Text = Range("=Functions!S17").Value
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    End If

'name series in legend
    Set srs1 = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    srs1.Name = "Margin"
    Set srs3 = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3)
    srs3.Name = "Less than 30 days"
    Set srs4 = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4)
    srs4.Name = "30 - 59 days"
    Set srs5 = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5)
    srs5.Name = "60 - 89 days"
    Set srs6 = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6)
    srs6.Name = "90 - 364 days"
    Set srs7 = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(7)
    srs7.Name = "365 days +"

'delete 2nd series, name axes, change chart type
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Delete
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Number of Reservations"
    .SeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = xlSecondary
    'next line was replaced with above line
    'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 2
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Margin Percentage"
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
End With

    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(0, 0, 100, 50).Select

    With Selection
        .OnAction = "DeleteGraph"
        .Name = "GraphButton"
        .Text = "Return to Margin View"
    End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
Here's the code I get for the unexpected HRESULT error.

```
Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)

Error Message:
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)

Error Message:
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Stack Trace:
Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.NativeExcelException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.NativeExcelFunctionsBase.ValidateResult(Int32 result, Int32[] expectedValues)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.NativeExcelFunctionsC2R.Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.INativeExcelFunctions.TryGetActiveListObject(IntPtr uiFrame, String& listObjectName)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.NativeWindowContext.TryGetActiveListObject(String& listObjectName)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ActiveQueryCache.ActiveListObjectDescriptor.GetActive(IWindowContext windowContext, IWorkbookServices workbookServices)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ActiveQueryCache.GetOrCreateCacheEntry(IWindowContext windowContext)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.CustomTaskPaneManagers.UpdateQueriesTaskPaneVisibility(IWindowContext windowContext)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelEventHandler.PerformPeriodicUpdate(IEnumerable`1 queriesTaskPaneVisibilityUpdateWindows)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.NativeEventHandler.<OnIdle>b__0()
at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)

Invocation Stack Trace:
at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.StackTraceInfo..ctor(String exceptionStackTrace, String invocationStackTrace)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Exception exception)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Native.NativeUserFeedbackServices.ReportException(IWin32Window activeWindow, WindowsHost windowsHost, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass1.<HandleException>b__0()
at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.SynchronizationContextExtensions.SendAndMarshalExceptions(SynchronizationContext context, Action callback)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.NativeEventHandler.OnIdle()
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.NativeExcelConnectorBase.<OnIdleCallback>b__37()
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelCallbackManager.InvokeAndReturnHResult(Action action)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.NativeExcelConnectorBase.OnIdleCallback()

Supports Premium Content:
False

Formulas:

section Section1;

    shared MarginalReportAnd2015 = let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("M:\Report Writing\Accounting-RAD\MARGINAL REPORT and 2015.xlsx"), null, true),
    Table2_Table = Source{[Item="Table2",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table2_Table,{{"Arrival Date", type any}, {"Reservation", Int64.Type}, {"Margin", type number}, {"Requested By", type text}, {"Billing Name", type any}, {"Length of Stay (days)", type any}})
in
    #"Changed Type";

shared SPIDE = let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("M:\Report Writing\Accounting-RAD\SPIde.xlsx"), null, true),
    SPIDE_Table = Source{[Item="SPIDE",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SPIDE_Table,{{"Arrival Date", type date}, {"Reservation", Int64.Type}, {"Margin", type number}, {"Requested By", type text}, {"Billing Name", type any}}),
    #"Column From Examples" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Literal", each "=INDEX('[TMR All Reservations.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D:$F,MATCH($B2,'[TMR All Reservations.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D:$D,0),3)", type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Column From Examples",{"Literal"}),
    #"Column From Examples1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Literal", each "REPLACE", type text),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Column From Examples1",{{"Literal", "Length of Stay (days)"}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Length of Stay (days)"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1";

[ Description = "Joins the SPIde report that must be ran and the 2015/Margin Report (2016)" ]
shared Append1 = let
    Source = Table.Combine({MarginalReportAnd2015, SPIDE})
in
    Source;
```

Comment: is the code in a module, form module, or worksheet module?  Which Object does it state is not defined?

Comment: @Sorceri The code is in a module. It doesn't tell me what object is not defined.

Comment: Which line is the error?

Comment: @0m3r I only get an error when I click the button to run the macro. It's the "user defined" error. It doesn't highlight anything within my code. If I step through the whole sub, I don't get the "user defined" error, just the "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC" error.

Comment: Normally, after you get a "User-defined type not defined." error, you should see the problematic declaration highlighted in blue.

Comment: `.ChartTitle.Text = Range("=Functions!T17").Value` this looks off

Comment: @TimWilliams Strangely, that won't give an error - it is equivalent to `.ChartTitle.Text = Worksheets("Functions").Range("T17").Value`

Comment: @YowE3K - huh, new to me...

Comment: @TimWilliams Ditto - but I tested it when I saw your comment.  Was wondering whether in fact it was actually some weird way of writing `.ChartTitle.Text = ActiveSheet.Range(Worksheets("Functions").Range("T17").Value).Value`, but it wasn't that sophisticated.

Comment: Yeah the `Range` property accepts an optional leading equals sign. It allows calling some functions (amazingly). E.g. `Range("=IF(A3,A1,A2)")` returns a reference to A1 if A3 is True, or a reference to A2 otherwise.

Comment: A search for the HRESULT code finds other issues that seem unrelated. Perhaps this code is generic from some sort of internal error, or is a catch all for different errors (and for some reason the actual error message is unhelpfully not displayed). Can you try putting a breakpoint in the code and when you click the button see if it reaches the breakpoint before failing? Then try moving the breakpoint around to see if you can deduce where it is failing.

Comment: Wasn't aware of breakpoints so thanks for pointing me in that direction for my know-how. However, when I set a breakpoint as early on as my lastrow variable or the displayalerts, I still got the User-defined error upon clicking the button. I then tried to step through it and as usual, it works. I then figured the button must not be mapped to the right macro. It said ....graph.graph which from what I remember in the past, sometimes would display that way. I decided to click on the option that only said "graph" and voila, it worked! I still have the HRESULT error though.

Comment: I pasted the "copy details" and it provided me a bunch of info I don't understand. Is there a way to clear this message? It doesn't look like the standard error box so it makes me think this is a MS issue, not VBA/Excel?

Comment: @andrew I've tried a new workbook with the macro:
Sub Graph()

Dim Chart As Chart

Set Chart = Charts.Add

End Sub

I still get the HRESULT error.

Comment: @Craig - can you paste the error details into the question?